# Laravel Guest Policies always return user as null unless using authentication middleware with Sanctum

Tags: laravel, authorization, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel Sanctum for authentication for an API and taking advantage of Policies for authorization.
The API has an endpoint to view a Post. Posts can either be draft or published. Anyone (including guests) can view published posts, but only admins can view draft posts.

The view policy looks like this:

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can view the model.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
 * @return mixed
 */
public function view(?User $user, Post $post)
{
    if($user && $user->isAdmin()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return $post->published;
    }
}
```

However, `$user` is always null, meaning the admins cannot view draft posts. But, if I run the `auth:sanctum` middleware on this route, it works fine for admins. However, that means then guest users get blocked from this endpoint because they are not authenticated.

My workaround currently is to use the `authorizeForUser(auth('sanctum')->user(), 'view', $post)` method to explicitly define the use. However, this forces me to break from the pattern used for other endpoints and doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Any solutions for this problem?

I have also noticed if I want to access the user on these routes, I need to explicitly specify to use the `sanctum` guard, i.e. `auth('sanctum')->user()`. Is there a config setting required always to use Sanctum as default?

Answer (score 2):

You can change your config file like this:

```
// config/auth.php

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'sanctum',
],
```